# AJAX FormData() vs encodeURI()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

jQuery uses the `encodeURI()`, so the data sent through AJAX is like this:

```
key1=true & key2=34 & ...
```

To send an image through AJAX, I use the `FormData()`, so the data from AJAX (without an image) is like:

```
-----------------------------7e136023611f0
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="key2"

34
```

Now I have two pure-JS functions for AJAX. The main one uses `encodeURI()`, and the other one is only for uploading images, using the `new FormData()`.

As I want to have only one AJAX function, my question is - would it be reasonable so switch only to the `FormData()`? What's the reason for jQuery to use the `encodeURI()`?

Comment: ... of course....

Comment: Those are two different methods of using ajax. FormData is used when POSTing data to the server, where the data will be placed in the body of the request. `encodeURI` is used when GETting data from the server, where the parameters are placed in the URL. Different functionality, different functions.

Comment: ... it's also possible to POST a request with the `encodeURI()`. Just specify the header 'Content-Type' = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Answer (score 0):

jQuery `$.ajax` accepts an object as datastring, so you could pass on the url of the image, or also use something like:

```
data = 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAAEwAMQAAJ2M5Me98GRK1D...1rTIIAQA7';
```

So you can then fetch and reconstruct the image on the other side.